# Can I Make A Duration Variable In Frame to Frame Animation xml?

Tags: android, android-animation

I have several Frame-to-Frame XML Animations that use the android:duration to set the speed.  All work well.

Is it possible to use a variable for this so I can change the values per user needs in code (using API 1.6).

The Frame Animation is less cumbersome than coding animation (and I already have 20 of them so I'd prefer a clever variable approach in XML).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Personally I found the animation XML too rigid, so I wrote an `AnimatedSprite` class that handed animations by looping through an `ArrayList` of `Drawable`s. If you implement the animation this way, it is as easy as creating a getter/setter method to make the speed changeable.

Comment: Thanks - though I'm not planning on doing animations in the future, I suppose I'll need to do something like that next time - just in case I later want to change duration.  Maybe I'll do it for this app before release, though I'd much prefer a clever xml variable approach.